# What is meant by memory hog?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I found the following statement:

> Reading in the whole file at one time is called slurping.
>   It can be useful but it may be a memory hog.

What is the meaning of *hog*, and how does it relate to the above statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The literal meaning of [hog](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hog?r=75) is "a full-grown pig".  Since pigs are typically greedy eaters, the figurative meaning of "hog" is "someone / something that consumes resources in a greedy or inconsiderate manner".
[image]
Typically a program or process would be described as a [memory hog](http://www.ldoceonline.com/Computers-topic/memory-hog) if it was written in such a way that it routinely allocates so much RAM that other processes are crowded out, or that the computer's performance is degraded.  Your quote is a little unusual in that it's talking about a technique - slurping - rather than a program, but the meaning is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I could find two [definitions](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/memory-hog), I think it refers to the first one:

> a computer program that uses a lot of memory
>
> someone who uses computer programs that use a lot of the power available, so that other people on the network have trouble using their programs

Longman Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

A *memory hog* is something that unfairly and unnecessarily keeps lots of memory for itself.

Consider other usages of "hog" in English, such as:

- *lane hog*: someone who drives down the middle lane on a motorway, wasting the inside lane
- *"he's hogging the bathroom"*: spending too much time maybe doing his hair; meanwhile nobody else can use the bathroom

As MT_Head explained, this originates from actual hogs, which are adult pigs. Adult pigs are greedy little feckers who will eat anything you give them with little or no due consideration for whether there's any feed left for their friends.

In computer programming you generally avoid reading the whole file at a time, instead reading and handling the data (say) line by line. Otherwise, you've just eaten up a huge chunk of memory that is no longer available for other programs to use.