# Someone/Something uses a lots of space (maybe more than really needed), what is this phenomenon called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I try to find a word for someone or something, who/which uses much space or more space than really needed.

Until now I tried to translate a German equivalent (but seemingly rarely used) "Platzfresser" into English with no success on leo.org. Some general search via google brought me "space hog", but I am not able to find any source for this, only some rare usage in newspapers around 2013.

Google translates "Platzfresser" to "space eater", which is too literally to my mind.

Is there a word, or short phrase, which describes someone/something (one or both), who/which uses too much space?

Comment: "Space hog" is actually a good colloquial phrase for taking up too much physical space. It's understandable to American English speakers, and it can be applied to people and to things. Somewhat related, "Footprint" is also a fairly recently popular term for amount of space or resource consumption, as in "air travel has a huge carbon footprint."

Comment: English tends to use verbs instead of nouns for this - they are *hogging the space*.

Answer (score 1):

Urban Dictionary has this to offer: **Space Eater**

> Any person that takes up more space than normal, either because they are big boned, a close talker, a pack rat, or just spreads out their ish over a wide area.

*"...you might want to step a side, it looks like there is a space eater coming this way..."*

or

*"I hate having conversations with that dude, he is such a space eater."*

or

*"With such as small apartment, I had no choice but to break it off with that space eater."*

Comment: Would it be possible, to use this term in the context of data on a device like a mobile phone or laptop?

Comment: @Allerleirauh - In the context of a program running on a computing device, I'd go with **memory hog**. .

Comment: @Allerleirauh— Doesn't sound too felicitous a choice for that kind of thing. Sorry, don't have a better word. :) But Canadian Yankee's suggestion sounds pretty good.

Comment: @CanadianYankee I agree! See also: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337497/what-is-meant-by-memory-hog